# Maintaining order of elements in unsorted linked list after removal of element

Tags: java, list

I was curious regarding a specific issue regarding unsorted linked lists. Let's say we have an unsorted linked list based on an array implementation. Would it be important or advantageous to maintain the current order of elements when removing an element from the center of the list? That hole would have to be filled, so let's say we take the last element in the list and insert it into that hole. Is the time complexity of shifting all elements over greater than moving that single element?

Comment: Can you clarify "unsorted linked list based on an array implementation"? `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` are different implementations of `List`. To give a generic answer: It depends on what you want it for, just make sure to state how the order is kept when adding/removing objects.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. ArrayUnsortedList is what I should have specified. I'm still learning how to ask the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove an item from a linked list without leaving a hole.

A linked list is not represented as an array of contiguous elements. Instead, it's a chain of elements with links. You can remove an element merely by linking its adjacent elements to each other, in a constant-time operation.

**Now, if you had an array-based list,** you could choose to implement deletion of an element by shifting the last element into position. This would give you O(1) deletion instead of O(n) deletion. However, you would want to document this behavior.

> Is the time complexity of shifting all elements over greater than moving that single element?

Yes, for an array-based list. Shifting all the subsequent elements is O(n), and moving a single element is O(1).

### java.util.List

If your list were an implementation of [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), note that java Lists are defined to be *ordered* collections, and the [List.remove(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) method is *defined* to shift the remaining elements.

Comment: My initial instinct was that the time complexity was substantially different between shifting elements and moving a single element. However, I don't have many strengths when it comes to measuring time complexity. Would this case be true for all arrays?

Comment: For all arrays of size *n*, if you want to shift up to *n* elements by copying them from one array index to another, it will take up to *n* copy operations, making the complexity O(n). You could think of the array like a row of boxes taped together. You can't move the boxes, but you can move the contents.  Presume you want to remove one of the items from a box before the last, and have no empty boxes. You can move the item from the last box in a single operation. But if you shift the items in all the other boxes, the time to do that will be proportional, worst-case, to the number of boxes.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helps me make a ton of sense out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using an array implementation it would have a larger time complexity up to n/2(if the element was in the middle of the array) to shift all entires over. Where moving one element would be constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using array the answer is yes, because you have to make multiple assignments.

If you would have used Nodes then it would be better in terms of complexity.